# submit values of custom checkbox in form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a div with a custom checkbox image.  It is in a form.  When clicked I alter the image to a "clicked image".  I also adjust the value of a checkbox input which will get submitted to the form.  The problem is even though the value of the "real" checkbox appears checked, it is always submitted as not checked.

```
    if (fakeCheck.hasClass('btn-palette-checkbox')) {
        fakeCheck.removeClass('btn-palette-checkbox');
        fakeCheck.addClass('btn-palette-checkbox-unchecked');
        $("#realCheck").attr("checked", false);
    }
    else {
        fakeCheck.addClass('btn-palette-checkbox');
        fakeCheck.removeClass('btn-palette-checkbox-unchecked');
        $("#realCheck").attr("checked", true);
    }
```

Edit: FYI the real checkbox is hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this to mark it as checked:

```
$("#realCheck").attr("checked", "checked");
```

And like this to uncheck it:

```
$("#realCheck").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 3):

From jQuery docs [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).  This is if you are using jQuery 1.6+

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value.

```
$("#realCheck").prop("checked", true);
$("#realCheck").prop("checked", false);
```

Read more about using .prop vs using .attr here
[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

`Checked`, like `disabled`, is a binary property, not an attribute. You need to use:

```
$("#realCheck").attr("checked", "checked");
```